# Powershell Script to Copy Folder and Content to remote location

Tags: powershell

I have written a power-shell script that copy the files from one location to another locally on server. I am trying to assemble the files at one server location and while doing this getting permission error. Script below:-

```
$date = (Get-Date).ToString("_MMddyyyy")

#Storing servers

$Servers = Get-Content C:\server.txt

#Scanning Servers and executing 

$Servers | ForEach-Object {

invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -Scriptblock {
$CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name


#Defining Source and Destination path

$DestPath =  "\\$CompName\d$\Temp\IIS_Logs_"+"$CompName"
$SourcePath = "\\$CompName\d$\Logs\W3SVC85\u_ex15122116.log"

#Creating new folder for storing backup

New-Item -Path $DestPath -ItemType directory

#Copying folder

copy -Recurse -Path $SourcePath -destination $DestPath 


}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the invoke command and after changing the logic script work as expected.

```
$date = (Get-Date).ToString("_MMddyyyy")

#Storing servers

$Servers = Get-Content C:\server.txt

#Scanning Servers and executing 

$Servers | ForEach-Object {

#Defining Source and Destination path

$DestPath =  "d:\Temp\IIS_Logs_"+"$_"
$SourcePath = "\\$_\d$\u_ex15122717.log"

#Creating new folder for storing backup

New-Item -Path $DestPath -ItemType directory

#Copying folder

Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $SourcePath -destination $DestPath 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an account that has rights to the admin share of D$?  If you are invoking that command on a remote machine to do local copying, you don't need to reference it like a network machine but just:
D:\Temp\IIS_Logs_"+"$CompName"

Comment: I am ruining the script through admin account. Also when i just provided the local location like above script is running fine and in powershell ISE debugger window it showing folder created but when i am seeing the local location folders are not there.

Comment: as of now folders are getting created on each server. What i want that all folders gets copied to one server insated of each server.

Comment: So you want each server to copy their contents to a single UNC that is not on the server you are working from?  You might be running into a delegation issue when you talk to a machine other than the machine you are remoting into.  Try with one of the servers mapping a drive to the other server you are trying to create the files at under the context of the user account you are using to run the script and make it persistent and then try to that drive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to it if you are not using shares, it can do:

- LocalToRemote
- RemoteToLocal
- RemoteToRemote

```
function MakeRemoteFolder($RemoteServer, $RemotePath)
{
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$RemotePath
        )
        If(!(test-path $RemotePath))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $RemotePath
        }
    } -ComputerName $RemoteServer -ArgumentList $RemotePath
}

function LocalToRemote($LocalPath, $RemoteServer, $RemotePath)
{
    Write-Host "Make folder on Remote Server"
    MakeRemoteFolder -RemoteServer $RemoteServer -RemotePath $RemotePath

    Write-Host "Send To Remote Server"
    $TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServer
    Copy-Item -Path $LocalPath -Destination $RemotePath -ToSession $TargetSession -Verbose -Recurse
}

function RemoteToLocal($LocalPath, $RemoteServer, $RemotePath)
{
    Write-Host "Make folder on local system"
    If(!(test-path $LocalPath))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $LocalPath
    }

    Write-Host "Receive From Remote Server"
    $TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServer
    Copy-Item -Path $RemotePath -Destination $LocalPath -FromSession $TargetSession -Verbose -Recurse
}

function RemoteToRemote($LocalDestinationPath, $LocalSourcePath, $RemoteServer1, $RemotePath1, $RemoteServer2, $RemotePath2)
{
    # Make sure that you have the space needed on the local system, not recomended for big files or folders.

    # Receive From Remote Server 1
    Write-Host "Make folder on local system"
    If(!(test-path $LocalDestinationPath))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $LocalPath
    }

    Write-Host "Receive From Remote Server 1"
    $TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServer1
    Copy-Item -Path $RemotePath1 -Destination $LocalDestinationPath -FromSession $TargetSession -Verbose -Recurse

    # Send To Remote Server
    Write-Host "Make folder on Remote Server 2"
    MakeRemoteFolder -RemoteServer $RemoteServer2 -RemotePath $RemotePath2

    Write-Host "Send To Remote Server 2"
    $TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServer2
    Write-Host "LocalSourcePath $($LocalSourcePath)"
    Copy-Item -Path $LocalSourcePath -Destination $RemotePath2 -ToSession $TargetSession -Verbose -Recurse
}

# LocalToRemote
Write-Host "LocalToRemote"
$FolderOrFileToSend = "LocalToRemote" # Eg. "Hallo World.txt" for a file

$LocalPath = "C:\Test\$($FolderOrFileToSend)"
$RemotePath = "C:\Test"
$RemoteServer = "RemoteServer"

LocalToRemote `
    -LocalPath $LocalPath `
    -RemoteServer $RemoteServer `
    -RemotePath $RemotePath


# RemoteToLocal
Write-Host "RemoteToLocal"
$FolderOrFileToSend = "RemoteToLocal" # Eg. "Hallo World.txt" for a file

$LocalPath = "C:\Test"
$RemotePath = "C:\Test\$($FolderOrFileToSend)"
$RemoteServer = "RemoteServer"

RemoteToLocal `
    -LocalPath $LocalPath `
    -RemoteServer $RemoteServer `
    -RemotePath $RemotePath


# RemoteToRemote
Write-Host "RemoteToRemote"
$FolderOrFileToSend = "RemoteToRemote" # Eg. "Hallo World.txt" for a file

$LocalDestinationPath = "C:\Test"
$LocalSourcePath = "C:\Test\$($FolderOrFileToSend)"
$RemotePath1 = "C:\Test\$($FolderOrFileToSend)"
$RemoteServer1 = "RemoteServer1"
$RemotePath2 = "C:\Test"
$RemoteServer2 = "RemoteServer2"

RemoteToRemote `
    -LocalDestinationPath $LocalDestinationPath `
    -LocalSourcePath $LocalSourcePath `
    -RemoteServer1 $RemoteServer1 `
    -RemotePath1 $RemotePath1 `
    -RemoteServer2 $RemoteServer2 `
    -RemotePath2 $RemotePath2
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will copy folder `<local-folder-path>` to a remote location specified by `<remote-folder-path>` below. The below functions assume you have a `$session`, `$MySecureCreds` and `$session` objects already setup.

```
$remoteFolderPath = "<remote-folder-path>"
createNewRemoteFolder $remoteFolderPath
cpItem "<local-folder-path>\*" $remoteFolderPath

function createNewRemoteFolder($newFolderPath) {

    $scriptStr = "New-Item -Path $newFolderPath -type directory -Force"
    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($scriptStr)

    runScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}

function runScriptBlock($scriptBlock) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $MySecureCreds -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}

function cpItem($from, $to) {

    Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination $to -ToSession $session -Verbose -Recurse
}
```